# ¿Como organizo mi código en diferentes archivos?

Tags: javascript, es6, ecmascript-2015, patrones-de-diseño

Actualmente mi código esta de la siguiente manera en un solo archivo de JavaScript:

```
function crearLienzo() {
}

function pintar() {
}

function seleccionarColor() {
}

//Resto de funciones...
```

Al haber muchas funciones ha llegado un punto que es difícil entenderlo por lo que quiero agrupar funciones que tengan una relación entre ellas en diferentes archivos.

¿Como podria hacerlo?

Comment: Parece ser una pregunta pregunta basada principalmente en opiniones y al mismo demasiado amplia pues se incluyen dos preguntas cuando cada publicación debería tener una única pregunta. Por otro lado falta indicar lo que has buscado/investigado sobre lo que se se está preguntando.

Comment: He intentado mejorar la pregunta y la descripcion del  problema. Necesito un poco de ayuda porque realmente no se muy bien como formular la pregunta, espero haberlo dejado algo mas claro. @Rubén

Comment: Deberías mirar los módulos de [ES2015+](https://programacionymas.com/blog/modulos-javascript-commonjs-amd-ecmascript) y empezar a trabajar con ellos, es el estándar actualmente

Comment: Gracias .Me parece muy buena la forma de trabajar con modulos de ES2015 pero me surge entonces otra duda... Este script es para una web. Si lo hago asi tendria varios archivos de js correspondientes a los diferentes modulos. ¿Desde la web tendria que hacer peticiones a todos los archivos? @PabloLozano

Comment: La web que te he enlazado está un poco desactualizada, cuando usas import en un navegador moderno el navegador ya es capaz de obtener los otros archivos sin tener que usar `<script>` para cada uno. Otra opción sería usar webpack o browserify para empaquetar los JS en un solo fichero, para asegurar la compatibilidad

Comment: Es justo lo que necesitaba y resuelve totalmente mi duda gracias @PabloLozano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dejo por aqui la solucion que me ha ayudado a encontrar @Pablo Lozano

Una de las novedades de ES6 (tambien conocido como ES2015) es la posibilidad de crear módulos.

Un módulo ES6 es un archivo que contiene código JS. Dentro de ellos pueden haber código, como clases, funciones, objetos o simples datos primitivos que podrán ser importados/exportados entre los diferentes archivos.

Siguiendo el ejemplo del problema que tenía en las que todas las funciones estaban en un solo archivo , la aplicación de esto sería la siguiente:

**1.** Creamos el primer modulo **miLienzo.js** que contendrá todas las funciones relacionadas con el lienzo. Como se puede observar al principio usa la sentencia export para que posteriormente estas funciones puedan ser importadas desde otro archivo js.

```
// miLienzo.js

export {crearLienzo, pintar};

function crearLienzo() {
}

function pintar() {
}
//Resto de funciones del modulo miLienzo
```

**2.** Hacemos lo propio con nuestro segundo módulo que es **paletaColores.js** . Nótese que hay varias formas de usar la sentencia export.

```
// paletaColores.js

export function seleccionarColor() {
}

// Resto de funcione del modulo paletaColores
```

**3.** Ahora que ya tenemos nuestros modulos creados habrá que importarlos en algún sitio, en este caso lo vamos hacer en un tercer archivo que será **main.js**

```
// main.js

import {crearLienzo, pintar} from './miLienzo.js';
import {seleccionarColor} from './paletaColores.js';

/* Ahora desde aqui podemos usar las funciones como si 
   las tuvieramos declaradas en este archivo*/

crearlienzo();
seleccionarColor();
pintar();
```

**4.** Por último al cargar nuestro archivo main.js desde nuestro documento html lo haremos de la siguiente manera:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**Importante** especificar type="module" de lo contrario el navegador puede interpretar el archivo como script normal y no como un módulo por lo que no funcionaría en el navegador.

**Nota:** Los módulos de ES6 están soportados por las últimas versiones de los navegadores actuales:

```
Safari 10.1.
Chrome 61.
Firefox 54 – behind the dom.moduleScripts.enabled setting in about:config.
Edge 16.
```

En cualquir caso existen trasnspiladores con los que podemos pasar nuestro codigo a ES5 siendo valido en versiones de los navegadores mucho mas antiguas. Algunos de ellos son:

```
Typescript, Babel, Webpack y Parcel
```

**Documentacion oficial:**

[ES6 Modulos: Import](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/import)

[ES6 Modulos: Export](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/export)

**Otra documentación:**

[Video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k-WZzLf1Q5o)